# Duplicate Excel Documents Opening After Interop

Tags: c#, excel, interop

My application functions as follows:

1. Takes user credentials.
2. Downloads a `.xls` document from a network location using these credentials to a temporary file.
3. Interfaces with this `.xls` document in the background using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` to update the user's outlook calendar (also using `Interop`).

The relevant method for parsing the `.xls` is as follows:

```
private static List<AppointmentDetails> ParseXls(string localSchedulePath, string initials)
        {
            List<AppointmentDetails> list = new List<AppointmentDetails>();
            List<string> alreadyCounted = new List<string>();
            Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(localSchedulePath);
            Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Sheets["On Call"];
            Excel.Range schedule = worksheet.Range["A1", "P369"];
            foreach (Excel.Range row in schedule.Rows)
            {
                foreach (Excel.Range cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    if (cell.Value == null || alreadyCounted.Contains(IndexToExcel(cell.Row, cell.Column))) continue;
                    if (cell.Value.ToString().Contains(initials))
                    {
                        List<int> rows = new List<int>();
                        int rowNum = cell.Row;
                        int colNum = cell.Column;
                        rows.Add(rowNum);
                        alreadyCounted.Add(IndexToExcel(rowNum, colNum));
                        while (schedule.Range[IndexToExcel(++rowNum, colNum)].Value != null &&
                        schedule.Range[IndexToExcel(rowNum, colNum)].Value.ToString().Contains(initials))
                        {
                            alreadyCounted.Add(IndexToExcel(rowNum, colNum));
                            rows.Add(rowNum);
                        }
                        string regionCode = worksheet.Range[IndexToExcel(1, colNum)].Value.ToString();
                        list.Add(new AppointmentDetails
                        {
                            StartDate = DateTime.Parse(worksheet.Range[IndexToExcel(rows[0], 2)].Value.ToString()),
                            EndDate = DateTime.Parse(worksheet.Range[IndexToExcel(rows[rows.Count - 1], 2)].Value.ToString()),
                            Region = regionCode
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            return list;
        }
```

This works absolutely fine, the calendar is updated and everything functions as it should. However, for some reason when the `.xls` is then manually opened from the SharePoint site so that a user can view it themselves, the temporary one that was just downloaded opens as well (with each one in a separate Excel window).

This isn't a major drama but I can't understand why this is happening and I'd rather get rid of a glitch if I can. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: this is happening because you are not cleaning up your excel instance in any way.  you never exit, close, cleanup resources, etc...if you were to look at the list of proceses after your process runs...youd see excel sitting out there

Comment: Ahh... I thought they'd automatically do that as they went out of scope... I've just discovered the Application.Quit() method a few minutes ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is quite a simple one. Thanks to @Ctznkane525 for pointing this out. Interop resources don't clean themselves up when they go out of scope. This needs to be done manually.

The following two lines of code were added to the bottom of the function in the question to suppress alerts and then close the application.

```
excel.DisplayAlerts = false;
excel.Quit();
```